# How to control string translation through camel to kebab filters and back again (this is a tip not a question)

Tags: filter, string

Putting this here in case anyone finds it useful.

Strings like 'ABC thing' when pushed through `camel` and `kebab` filters can cause unexpected issues. For example…

```
{% set str = 'ABC thing' %}
{% set key = str|camel %}
{% set id  = key|kebab %}
{% set keyFromId = id|camel %}

{# 
  key       = 'aBCThing'
  id        = 'a-bc-thing'
  keyFromId = 'aBcThing'
#}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to invoke `lower` first:

```
{% set str = 'ABC thing' %}
{% set key = str|lower|camel %}
{% set id  = key|kebab %}
{% set keyFromId = id|camel %}

{# 
  key       = 'abcThing'
  id        = 'abc-thing'
  keyFromId = 'abcThing'
#}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tip! If you could mark the solution as the "accepted answer" it'll close this topic out as resolved and allow others to browse it as a complete solution. It's totally valid to accept your own answer to a question :)